# Why's this not working? Turn's value is incrementing but it still triggers the same event?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

So, I've decided to create a Tic Tac Toe game on JS, but when I try to decide the turn of X or O, it doesn't change. I've tried to use the modulus logic so variable increments via one thus changing the turn if it's an even or an odd number. But the below code doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help find the error in here?

```
const secs = document.querySelectorAll('.sec');
  let turn = 1;

if (turn%2===0){
    for (sec of secs){
    sec.removeEventListener('click', oturn);
    sec.addEventListener('click', xturn);
} } 
else if (turn%2!= 0) {
    for (sec of secs){
    sec.removeEventListener('click', xturn);
    sec.addEventListener('click', oturn);
}}


function xturn (e){
 e.target.innerHTML = "X";
 ++turn
 console.log(turn);
}

function oturn (e){
 e.target.innerHTML = "O";
 ++turn
 console.log(turn);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you'd check the state and attach/detach the events only onece, when the page loads. If that's not the case, we need more context. In any case, toggling events for the task is a bit overkilling, it would be much simpler to change the value of the content according to the state.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gf65s7k4/). It's best to create a "model" of the game in JS, and then update the view according to the state of the model.

Comment: tysm! btw can you explain me the logic of line 7 (js), current = +!current; mainly the operators

Comment: Unary `+` converts the boolean unary `!` returns, to a number, i.e. the line toggles the value of `current` between 0 and 1.

Comment: You should provide some more details.

Comment: Tysm @Teemu! It really helped a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function after declaring them

just add these lines at the end

xturn(e);
oturn(e);

Comment: The functions are attached to click events, and are called when a visitor clicks on an element.